# How to bind parameters as arguments to MYSQL IN()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following query is supposed to return three rows, but it returns only one:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE state = ? AND id IN(?) AND status IN(?)");
$sql->execute(array(1, '1,2,3', '1,2,3'));
```

However, the same query executed without bound parameters as the argument to the `IN()` function returns 3 rows, as it's supposed to:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE state = ? AND id IN(1,2,3) AND status IN(1,2,3)");
$sql->execute(array(1));
```

Why does this happen, and how do I correctly bind `1,2,3` as the argument to `IN()`?

Comment: An explanation: [Prepared statements and IN clause](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in)

Comment: This explanation actually provided a response (given there are other placehoders in my query), contrary to the question this is marked as a duplicate of which deals with a single placeholder. The solution here is thus to use `array_merge` to join all variables into a single array. Thanks, @YourCommonSense